# Showing relationship between two raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have two separate raster layers, one containing sediment transport rate and another raster containing stream length. Now, I want to show the relationship between sediment transport change in different stream length. How should I proceed?

I tried using the profile tool in ArcGIS but that gives me only one raster value against the profile distance. But I want Sediment transport rate against stream distance.

Comment: You might need to combine the rasters http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Combine/009z0000007r000000/ but if both are floating point you will need to classify the rasters first.